# Does concrete sealant slow the growth of moss?

Tags: concrete, patio, moss

Does sealant like Thompson's WaterSeal slow the growth of moss on concrete?  I live in the rainy Pacific Northwest and moss and mold are regular problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a *way* it does. It's a lot like Rain-X makes water bead up on glass, masonry sealant will make the water *tend to* bead up and run off of brick and concrete. However, much like Rain-X, it wears out every once in a while -- probably more often in the PNW where it'll get wet all the time.

The moss grows because there's easy moisture to be found within and on top of the brick. However, the sealant won't prevent moisture that's deposited on the brick by fog / mist or dew from collecting -- all three things are common in the PNW due to the relatively high humidity. Therefore, it'll help a bit, but it's not a total or even ideal solution.

Although -- the Thompson's sealant is not the best on the market by far. Look at the Behr stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have a brick patio and found that oddly enough where I installed a silicone seal about 1 inch wide between two areas of the bricks NOTHING grows within 4 inches of either side of the sealer; everywhere else shade or sun something eventually grows. The sealant has be effective for at least 5 years or more. Like to know what is in it.

Comment: So you have anecdotal evidence that the sealant does prevent moss from growing. Please [edit] your post to say what type of sealant you use as it may be helpful to other users. Thanks!